# It keep giving me the syntax error message when I can't find why it won't allow it

Tags: python-3.x

I was doing the assignment when this came up and as I am just a beginner I have no idea what is going on or how to solve it.
All the commented parts are just me trying out different ways to do it.

```
import  sys
# YOUR CODE HERE
#small = input("Width, Height and Depth of small box: ")
#big = input("Width, Height and Depth of big box: ")

small_width = input("What is the width of the small box? ")
small_height = input("What is the height of the small box? ")
small_depth = input("What is the depth of the small box? ")

#small = 0
small = int(small_width)*int(small_height)*int(small_depth)

big_width = input("What is the width of the big box? ")
big_height = input("What is the height of the big box? ")
big_depth = input("What is the depth of the big box? ")

#big = 0
big = int(big_width)*int(big_height)*int(big_depth)

num = big%small
num = int(num)

print(num)

#if int(num) > 0
    #print("Number of " + small + " that will fit in " + big + " is: " + num)
#else:
    #print("Number of " + small + " that will fit in " + big + " is: 0")
```

It keeps saying this part is wrong.

```
#if int(num) > 0
               ^
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon after the if statement.
Download and install PyCharm (there is a free edition) - the IDE will highlight such errors.

```
import  sys
# YOUR CODE HERE
#small = input("Width, Height and Depth of small box: ")
#big = input("Width, Height and Depth of big box: ")

small_width = input("What is the width of the small box? ")
small_height = input("What is the height of the small box? ")
small_depth = input("What is the depth of the small box? ")

#small = 0
small = int(small_width)*int(small_height)*int(small_depth)

big_width = input("What is the width of the big box? ")
big_height = input("What is the height of the big box? ")
big_depth = input("What is the depth of the big box? ")

#big = 0
big = int(big_width)*int(big_height)*int(big_depth)

num = big%small
num = int(num)

print(num)

if int(num) > 0:
    print("Number of {} that will fit in {} is: {}".format(small, big, num))
    # print("Number of " + small + " that will fit in " + big + " is: " + num)
else:
    # print("Number of " + small + " that will fit in " + big + " is: 0")
    print("Number of {} that will fit in {} is: {}".format(small, big, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon(`:`) at the end of the `if` statement. If you add it you will see that your problem on that line is fixed, but you will have another problem in the `print` statement of the `if` condition because you will be printing a text result trying to concatenate int variables.